# Github action self-hosted runner override the env vars - how can I configure my own env vars?

Tags: kubernetes, github, environment-variables, workflow, action

Github action self-hosted runner overrides the env vars

It runs shell commands with --no-profile --norc so I can't add the env vars in the profile/bashrc files.

I saw inside .env file that there are a few vars that are listed by env.sh under -
varCheckList...
How can I configure my own env vars without being overritten when an agent starts?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Linux, could be use the file `/etc/environment` to load your variables.

In your host you can just put `echo 'export MY_ENV=value' >> /etc/environment`